# How to Cancel AlarmManager in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have an alarm that will not go off until specific hour and minute.  However, once that time comes, it will go off everytime I start the app again.  (When the app starts it resets and check for a new alarm).

For example, it will go off at 9:48 AM.  Before 9:48 nothing happens as expected.  But AFTER 9:48, it will keep going off everytime the app starts (The alarm is a simple status bar notification).

Here is code -- where did I go wrong?

// Alarm set here - this code is called each time app starts up

```
public void setAlarm() {
 for (int i : AlarmDays) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > i)
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 53);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);


        String Name = AlarmNames.get(count);
        count = 0 + 1;

        Intent intent = new Intent(ManageDebts.this, TimeAlarm.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("keyvalue", Name);
        intent.putExtras(b);


        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);

    }
 }
```

TimeAlarm.class

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

NotificationManager nm;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String DebtName = intent.getStringExtra("keyvalue");

    nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence from = "Payment Due: " + DebtName;
    CharSequence message = "Update your Balance Now";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ManageDebts.class);
    notificationIntent.getExtras();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Pay "
            + DebtName + " today!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
    notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
            | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notif.ledOnMS = 100;
    notif.ledOffMS = 100;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(1, notif);
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure you are not setting any alarms in the past (e.g., 9:48 for today when it is after 9:48).

Comment: It looks like that is exactly what I am doing.  Where do I set it to ignore any Alarms that are NOT in that minute, hour and second?  before OR after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I set it to ignore any Alarms that are NOT in that minute, hour and second? before OR after?

In your `setAlarm()` method. Either filter things out from `AlarmDays` before you go in the loop, or compare `cal.getTimeInMillis()` to `System.currentTimeMillis()` to see if it is in the past, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you.  I went with a comparison if statement.  Worked great.